# Regex matching year

Tags: regex, elixir

I am trying to match years beginning 19 or 20 using this regex

```
/(19|20)\d{2}/
```

```
name = "My example 2004-2005"
years = Regex.scan(~r/(19|20)\d{2}/, name)
IO.inspect(years)
```

I expect

```
["2004", "2005"]
```

but am getting

```
[["2004", "20"], ["2005", "20"]]
```

I have no idea why I am getting `"20"` returned as well. I also tried

```
/(19|20){1}\d{2}/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you wrap the `19|20` in a pair of parentheses, you create a capture group. This represents a sub-match. To create a group but not make it count as a separate sub-capture, use a non-capturing group. It has this syntax: `(?:)`

So in your example, it would be:

```
/(?:19|20)\d{2}/
```

However, the results will still be a list of lists:

```
[["2004"], ["2005"]]
```

Use `List.flatten()` to flatten the list into a one-dimensional list:

```
IO.inspect(List.flatten(years))
```

Answer (score 0):

To return the whole capture only, one can use [capture modifier `capture: :first`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#module-captures) passed as the third parameter to [`Regex.scan/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#scan/3).

It would nevertheless return the list of lists, hence you’ll need to flatten the result either with `List.flatten/1` of with a comprehension

```elixir
for [c] <- Regex.scan(~r/(19|20)\d{2}/, name, capture: :first), do: c  
#⇒ ["2004", "2005"]
```

Comment: Interesting, i need to learn about comprehension. I actually want to return the last year and I know the idomatic way is to use `Enum.take(-1)` but i would like to go from `[["year"]]` to `"year"` - what is the best way to do that?

Comment: The whole year (the match for the whole regex) is indeed always **the first match**. That said, `capture: :first` works for discarding group matches from the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case it is clearer if you first extract the years using [`String.split/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/3), then use [`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) to filter the valid years using a regular expression:

```elixir
"My example 2004-2005-1816-1905-401"
|> String.split(["My example ", "-"], trim: true)
|> Enum.filter(&(&1 =~ ~r/(19|20)\d{2}/))
```

Result:

```elixir
["2004", "2005", "1905"]
```

Comment: `Enum.filter(&Regex.match?(~r/(19|20)\d{2}/, &1))`, if you prefer.